# Tap outside picker text not opening picker menu

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a `Picker` like this

```
Picker ("", selection: $itemIndex){
    ForEach (0..<items.count, id: \.self){ index in
        Text(items[index])
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(.red)
```

The issue is that the picker extends to the screen width but the text displaying on the Picker is not that lengthy, maybe about 1/20 of the Picker length

Now when I click on the text, the Picker menu opens up, but when I click outside the text, still within the picker visibility, the menu don't open.

[image]

In the image above, when I tap on the red side, the menu opens up, but when I tap on both green sides it doesn't

Do anyone have an idea why this is happening?

**Note:** the picker is not in a `Form` or a `NavigationController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... So through the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387836/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-tappable-area-of-a-picker-in-swiftui), I was able to customize my own `Picker` style. Below is the code to achieve this

```
struct CustomPickerStyle: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var index: Int
    var items: [String]
    var font: SwiftUI.Font
    var padding: CGFloat
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Menu {
            content
        } label: {
            HStack {
                if let labelText = items[index] {
                    Text(labelText)
                        .font(font)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "triangle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 8)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                }
            }
            .padding(padding)
            .frame(alignment: .leading)
            .background(Colors.white)
        }
    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    func customPickerStyle(index: Binding<Int>, items: [String], font: SwiftUI.Font, padding: CGFloat) -> some View {
        self.modifier(CustomPickerStyle(index: index, items: items, font: font, padding: padding))
    }
}
```

And I this is how I used it in my UI

```
Picker("", selection: $itemIndex){
    ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self){ index in
        Text(items[index])
    }
}
.customPickerStyle(index: $itemIndex, items: items, font: .system(size: 17), padding: 10)
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1.0))
```

And here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted this

```
Picker ("", selection: $itemIndex){
    ForEach (0..<items.count, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(items[index])
           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)    // << here !!
    }
}
.background(.red)
```

or this if you told about `Menu`

```
    Menu {

      // content here

    } label: {
        Text("Menu")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)    // << here !!
    }
```

the general rule is - give space for label which is actually shown, instead of containing control, because hit testing is usually set up by intrinsic content.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, then needed minimal reproducible example... guessing has low efficiency.